# Gerar tabela em PHP com dados específicos para MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela numa base de dados MySQL, e preciso gerar com PHP uma tabela, mas não é uma tabela trivial. A minha tabela tem os seguintes campos: `codigo`, `item`, `preco` e `quantidade`.
Preciso gerar uma tabela onde por exemplo eu tenha os seguintes dados:

```
codigo = BC0001
item = molas tipo 2
preco = 5.92
quantidade = 10
```

A minha linha na tabela tem uma limitação de apenas 5 colunas.
Já consegui gerar uma tabela que repete as linhas com base no valor de quantidade, o problema é que quando a quantidade é `= 10` como no exemplo acima, ele cria 10 linhas de 5 colunas e eu preciso que sejam criadas apenas duas linhas.

Se por exemplo a quantidade for `= 7`, terá que preencher uma linha e completar a linha com dados de outros itens, que tenham quantidade `= 1, 3, 5` etc.
Alguma dica?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código que gera essas tabelas?

Comment: Como você descobre quantas linhas (registros) terá a sua tabela? Sempre serão duas linhas? Como será?

Comment: Olha Shura16, então, não existe um padrão pois a quantidade pode variar muito, poucas vezes eu terei duas ou mais linhas de um mesmo produto, a maioria dos meus produtos tem quantidade <= 5, pode ser 1, 3, alguns tem acima de 10, não existe um padrão.